# Show that the following functional is Frechet differentiable in Hilbert space

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I need to show that the following functional is Frechet differentiable:

$$
f(u) = \|u\|^2_{H} \ \ \text{in a real Hilbert space} \ \  H
$$

Solution:

As far as I understand, I need to take a Taylor expansion:
$$
f(u+h) = \|u+h\|^2_{H}
$$
and use the Frechet differentiability formula:
$$
F(u+h)=F(u)+Ah+r(u,h)
$$
However, I don't know how to get a Taylor expansion of such norm and also I don't really understand how to get the Frechet differentiability formula of the results. I would appreciate any help and explanation as I don't really understand how Frechet derivative works...

Answer (score 2):

A Taylor expansion would be kind of circular, since a Taylor expansion requires differentiability, and that is what you want to prove.

However, noting that $f(u) = \lVert u\rVert_H^2 = \langle u,u\rangle_H$, it is not difficult to get an expansion of $f(u+h)$ using the properties of the inner product (the one you need is bilinearity). This expansion then turns out to be the Taylor expansion, but we know that only after the fact.

So the strategy is to expand $f(u+h)$ by bilinearity, and then collect

- the terms independent of $h$,
- the terms linear in $h$,
- the remaining terms,

and check (prove) that they do what is desired.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. So after the expansion I got:
$$
f(u+h) = \|u\|^2_{H}+2t<u,h>_{H}+\|h\|^2_{H}
&&
Is it right? How should I proceed with the following instructions you have mentioned?

Comment: The $t$ in $2t\langle u,h\rangle_H$ is probably just a typo? $\lVert u\rVert_H^2$ is $f(u)$, you know where that belongs. Then we have one term linear in $h$, and one quadratic. So it's a safe bet that the linear term, $h\mapsto 2\langle u,h\rangle_H$ will be the derivative. Prove it.

Comment: Sorry, t was a typo. Thus we have:f(u) + 2<u,h>_{H} + ||h||^2_{H}.
I still don't understand how to prove it..

Comment: You have the general expression $F(u+h) = F(u) + Ah + r(u,h)$. Here, $F(u) = \lVert u\rVert_H^2$, $Ah = 2\langle u,h\rangle_H$, $r(u,h) = \lVert h\rVert_H^2$. To show differentiability, what properties of $A$ and $r$ do you need to show?